# Usage of the word "autonomous" to refer to time-invariant differential equations

Tags: mathematics, terminology

At what point in time did the term "autonomous" begin to signify time-invariance within the context of dynamical systems, and what prompted this association?

Comment: The Google Ngram Viewer shows when "autonomous dynamical system" appeared in published books (in English): https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=autonomous+dynamical+system&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3